# synchronize local Debian time with amazon Debian instances (RDS) MDT to UTC

Tags: shell, datetime, amazon-web-services, debian

it tried this command on my amazon Debian instances

```
    root@ip-:~# date
    Sun Apr 27 11:26:34 UTC 2014
```

and in my local debain instances its like this

```
  root@debian:~# date
  Sun Apr 27 16:56:56 MDT 2014
```

so now how can i make my local debain machine time as same as the amazon instance time

i.e

convert

```
   Sun Apr 27 16:56:56 MDT 2014 ->(to) Sun Apr 27 11:26:34 UTC 2014 this
```

in my local debain machinee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues concerning the time difference at hand:

1. **Timezone** - your local Debian system is running with your local timezone, whereas the EC2 instance is running with [Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). The latter is pretty much the norm and resp. best practice for servers, you can adjust your local system via `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` (see Ynhockey's answer to [How do I permanently reset the time zone in Debian?](https://superuser.com/a/545936/5441)).
2. **Precision** - either one or both of your systems exhibit significant clock skew against UTC (both times should be identically after subtracting the timezone offset). This is easily remedied by installing a [Network Time Protocol (NTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) daemon to [Set the time automatically](https://wiki.debian.org/DateTime#Set_the_time_automatically) as explained in Debian's [DateTime](https://wiki.debian.org/DateTime), which boils down to `sudo apt-get install ntp` and editing `/etc/ntp.conf` to target more [local NTP server sources](http://www.pool.ntp.org/zone/@) for optimal results.