# AWS: IAM user policies for SES not working

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, amazon-iam

I'm trying to run the following PHP code on my server:

```
require 'aws_sdk_php/aws-autoloader.php';
use Aws\Ses\SesClient;

echo 'teste1';
$client = SesClient::factory(array(
    'key' => 'xxxxx',
    'secret' => 'yyyyy',
    'region' => 'us-east-1'
));
echo 'teste2';
echo $client->listIdentities();
echo 'teste3';
echo $client->verifyEmailIdentity(array(
    'EmailAddress' => 'my_email@gmail.com'
));
```

I created a user with permission to send emails using SMTP (ses:SendRawEmail) and it works just fine. However the "listIdentities" and "verifyEmailIdentity" calls only works when I grant SES Full Access permission or use full credentials for the account.

If I add only "ses:ListIdentities" and "ses:VerifyEmailIdentity" to the same user, I get a 403 error saying the signature not match. Anybody have any idea what's going on? Do I have to add other permissions/policies to grant access to this calls?

I also ran this permissions on the IAM Policy Simulator and they passed when they were set, but I received a "denied" after I removed them.

Thanks!

---

Update: According to this [SES AWS Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch, Status Code: 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459155/ses-aws-error-code-signaturedoesnotmatch-status-code-403) MAYBE the fix is I should adjust the time on my EC2 server, but how can I found out what time is it on SES servers since I don't have access to them?

---

Update2: Doesn't seem like a case of diferent time, as I ran the code on a server on North Virginia and got the same results. Permissions passed on the simulator. Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of the [AWS SDK for PHP](https://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/) are you using?

Comment: The version I'm using has this on SesClient.php file: const LATEST_API_VERSION = '2010-12-01';

Answer (score 1):

> [...] MAYBE the fix is I should adjust the time on my EC2 server, but how can I found out what time is it on SES servers since I don't have access to them?

The "clock skew" mentioned in [Jeremy Lindblom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22460549/45773) means that the time on your server isn't sufficiently synchronized with [Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) *after* subtracting the timezone offset, i.e. you do not actually need to know the time on the [Amazon SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) servers (which most certainly is simply UTC though), rather just ensure that your own system is synchronized with UTC too (no matter what timezone you are in) - see my answer to [synchronize local Debian time with amazon Debian instances (RDS) MDT to UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23322985/45773) for more details on the subject and how to resolve this for a Debian/GNU resp. Ubuntu system:

> [...] This is easily remedied by installing a [Network Time Protocol (NTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) daemon to [Set the time automatically](https://wiki.debian.org/DateTime#Set_the_time_automatically) as explained in Debian's [DateTime](https://wiki.debian.org/DateTime), which boils down to sudo apt-get install ntp and editing /etc/ntp.conf to target more [local NTP server sources](http://www.pool.ntp.org/zone/@) for optimal results.

Comment: That still didn't worked. Trying to confirm if the problem indeed is a diference of time by creating an instance in the same region of SES (North Virginia), but for some strange reason I'm not gettins ssh access for the server. I receive a "timeout error" when I try to ssh (and yes I have granted ssh access on security groups).

Comment: Used the same code on a EC2 server on North Virginia, but still got the same error, so a diference between time is probably not the cause of the error. Permissions passed the test on the simulator. Anyone have an idea what is going on?